# Error getting data from AngularFire

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I am trying to set data to my table.
I have a service that should retrieve data like this:

```
  constructor(public af: AngularFire, userData: UserData) {
    this.smartTableData = af.database.list('events/' + userData.user.uid +'/contacts');
  }

  getData(): any {
    return this.smartTableData;
  }
```

and my component is:

```
 constructor(protected service: SmartTablesService) {
    this.service.getData().then((data) => {
      this.source.load(data);
    });
  }
```

my error from console:

> zone.js:357 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in
>   ./SmartTables class SmartTables_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by:
>   this.service.getData(...).then is not a function(…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularFire2 works with Observables, which you `subscribe` to.
The error you are getting is because you are trying to call an undefined function `then`, which is available in Promises, not Observables.

You want to replace `then` with `subscribe` to retrieve the data.

```
constructor(protected service: SmartTablesService) {
   this.service.getData().subscribe((data) => {
     this.source.load(data);
   });
}
```